# How to ensure the node and volume availability zones (AZs) within an AWS EKS Cluster remain consistent during node group rolling upgrades?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I'm having trouble ensuring my pods re-connect to their PVs after an AWS EKS node group rolling upgrade. The issue is that the node itself moves from AZ `us-west-2b` to `us-west-2c`, but the PVs remain in `us-west-2b`.

The label on the node is `topology.kubernetes.io/zone=us-west-2c` and the label on the PV remains `topology.kubernetes.io/zone=us-west-2b`, so the volume affinity check warning shows up on the spinning pods after the upgrade finishes:

`0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.`

[Per the AWS upgrade docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-update-behavior.html):

> When upgrading the nodes in a managed node group, the upgraded nodes
> are launched in the same Availability Zone as those that are being
> upgraded.

But that doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a way I can always enforce the creation of nodes into the same AZ they were in prior to the upgrade?

Note: this is a 1-node AWS EKS Cluster (with a max set to 3), though I don't think that should matter.

Comment: You should generally have one node group per AZ instead of one group with multiple AZs for handling PVs. I believe the cluster-autoscaler docs state similar, but here is the relevant section of the EKS best practices guide: https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/cluster-autoscaling/#ebs-volumes

Comment: The gist is that this is a limitation of AWS autoscaling groups. If you have a mult-az group, you can not request an instance in a specific AZ (which you require for volume attachment)

Comment: Aha, thanks @jordanm - so during EKS node group creation, restricting the node group to a single AZ is the solution to ensure subsequent upgrades never create the node outside of the single AZ (and PVs and nodes then stay in the same AZ)?

Comment: Yes, that should solve the issue of it trying to replace with an instance of the wrong AZ, but if you are also using cluster-autoscaler, note the `balance-similar-node-groups=true` config setting is also required for things to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is possible, you need to enforce the AZ for the node group when you create it. When using kubectl you can use cli:

```
eksctl create cluster --name=cluster --zones=eu-central-2a,eu-central-2b --node-zones=eu-central-2a
```

When using terraform:

```
  module "eks" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version         = "= 14.0.0"
  cluster_version = "1.17"
  cluster_name    = "cluster-in-one-az"
  subnets         = ["subnet-a", "subnet-b", "subnet-c"]

  worker_groups = [
    {
      instance_type = "m5.xlarge"
      asg_max_size  = 5
      subnets  = ["subnet-a"]
    }
  ]
```

Where the subnet-a belongs to the desired availability zone where your PV was created.